# Randomly generating a value in an XML using values from another XML

Tags: xml

I have an xml file that I want to generate a random value from another xml file. How can I get the two xml files to link?

For example my news.xml has headlines:

```
<news>
    <newsItem>
        <headline>Headline</headline>
        <date></date>
        <desc><![CDATA[<p>News Data</p>]]></desc>
    </newsItem>
</news>
```

My planets.xml has locations:

```
<planets>
    <planet>
        <xcood>-123.764</xcood>
        <ycood>272.182</ycood>
        <id>ID</id>
        <name>Name</name>
    </planet>
</planets>
```

I want to be able to have the news item generate a random planet from the planets.xml. In the method of:

```
<news>
    <newsItem>
        <headline>Headline</headline>
        <date></date>
        <desc><![CDATA[<p>News Data {insert planet name here}</p>]]></desc>
    </newsItem>
</news>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is a passive data format.  Generating random values would have to be done via an external program.

Update to address follow-up in comments:

**For passive XML referencing mechanisms, see:**

1. [External entities](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-external-ent) or [XInclude](https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/) for embedding
2. [XLink](https://www.w3.org/TR/xlink11/) for referencing

Note that support for external entities is strongest as it's directly built in to all conforming XML parsers.

Comment: Okay, understood . Can I add a line into the XML to have it reference another XML file? The program that is using the XML is running in Java.